# Laravel 5.2 session flash doesn't work the first time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**UPDATE:** My issue had nothing to do with Laravel sessions, it was my Service Worker that was causing sessions to mess up! Although I still don't understand why the service worker was fine for a different hostname with the same code, but after disabling it sessions work fine now! Will leave this here in case anyone else stumbles upon session issues and don't immediately think about any service workers they have.

---

Since migrating to Laravel 5.2 I've been having session persistence problem with `Session::flash` and subsequent `Session::keep` usage.

I know I'm supposed to use the `web` middleware group, and I am. But that isn't solving my problem. Please see below:

app/Http/Kernel.php

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ]
];
```

app/Http/routes.php

```php
Route::get('test', function(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->flash('test_flash', "Some value");
    return redirect('/flashed');
});
Route::get('flashed', function(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->reflash();
    return redirect('/flash-kept');
});
Route::get('flash-kept', function(Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->session()->get('test_flash'));
});
```

The first time I hit `/test` it redirects to `/flash-kept` with value of `test_flash` as `NULL` - but second time I hit it, again it redirects but this time with correct value! And this is consistent in that every time I load any other page, then load `/test` it doesn't keep the flash message, only second time hitting it does.

Can someone see anything wrong??

This is happening on a Debian machine running `PHP 5.6.30`, very interestingly I cannot replicate this behaviour on my local machine, macOS running `PHP 7.1` - but I don't think it's PHP version either as I quickly tried downgrading my local machine to use PHP 5.6 and I still couldn't re-create the issue! I've been staring at this for the last few hours, cannot see anything wrong!

Comment: I'm just guessing, what session driver you're currently using? double check it's the same in the production (clear the config cache, check .env file ...), try to change it to something else just for testing

Comment: I have already tried different cache drivers; it was using `file` locally and in production, changed it to `redis`, still the same

Comment: maybe you didn't migrate all files, check the "Files changed" tab under [Comparing changes](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/5.1...5.2), especially `RouteServiceProvider.php` and `Http/Kernel.php`. To assert it's not a Laravel issue, create a completely new laravel 5.2 in prod (use a different port or a subdomain), and copy your routes, it's a pretty small code to test.

Comment: @Razor thanks, please see my update on the question

Comment: @mavili hey did you find a solution for this? I have the same error now.
Works fine on staging server and local, but does only save the second session on production.

Comment: @SimonEritsch unfortunately not. As I put it in the update, I concluded that because the service worker in the browser was intercepting requests before sending to the server, my session data was being messed up. Don't know why and didn't have the opportunity to follow it further